# Get Post Meta from ID in functions.php

Tags: php

I have the following in my theme's `functions.php` script.

```
function add_to_system( $appointment_id ) { 
    $name = get_post_meta( $appointment_id, '_appointment_guest_name', TRUE ); 
    $email = get_post_meta( $appointment_id, '_appointment_guest_email', TRUE ); 
    $telephone = get_post_meta( $appointment_id, '_cf_meta_value', TRUE ); 
    mail( "michael.mcgurk87@yahoo.co.uk","Test Email", $name.$email.$telephone.$appointment_id );
}
add_action( 'booked_new_appointment_created', 'add_to_system', 99, 1 );
```

However, when I test by making a booking, it just sends the `appointment_id` in the body of the email. It doesn't grab the post meta data associated with that ID. Am I doing something wrong here?

N.B. it's for this plugin: https://codecanyon.net/item/booked-appointments-appointment-booking-for-wordpress/9466968/comments?page=50&filter=all#comment_12081430.

Comment: Do a `var_dump( get_post_meta( $appointment_id ) );` in the function and see if you're actually using the correct meta keys. Some data like telephone number might also be empty.

Comment: That pulls the data as expected but it doesn't in `functions.php` :(

Comment: Where did you add the `var_dump()`?

Comment: I created a separate file in my root called `test.php` with the following code: 

`require ('./wp-blog-header.php');
$appointment_id = "4770";
$name = get_post_meta($appointment_id,'_appointment_guest_name',true);
echo $name;`

Comment: Maybe the hook no longer exists.. try `var_dump( did_action( 'booked_new_appointment_created' ) );` in that test file, right after the `require` line. What do you see?

Comment: Hmm. It's strange. `test.php` works perfectly btw, it outputs the name as expected. But the function in `functions.php` still doesn't seem to get the data and pass it to the email :(

Answer (score 0):

get_post_meta( $appointment_id, '_appointment_guest_name', TRUE );

> please make sure that $appointment_id will be the post id and meta_key name should be proper with that id
>   you can check this in wp_postmeta table(check meta_key name is _appointment_guest_name or appointment_guest_name)